# Designing in a mongo way

Tags: mongodb, database

Im new to mongo, I dont get it all. In mySQL I have something like this:

## Schedule

**|Hour | Saturday | Sunday | Monday**
**|13:00|** Math |Spanish |Biology |Chemistry|
**|14.00 |** Subject |Subject |Subject| Subject|

How I can design it, but in a *mongo* way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would nest the days of the week inside a single document (a record) and inside of each of the days, you would have key value pairs of `time : subject`

```
{
    _id: "....",
    saturday: {
        13: "math",
        14: "history"
    },
    sunday: {
        15: "biology",
        16: "chemistry"
    }
}
```

This can be even more detailed if you want, such as including the name of the teacher:

```
{
    _id: "....",
    saturday: {
        13: { 
            subject: "math",
            teacher: "Mr. Smith"
        },
        14: { 
            subject: "history",
            teacher: "Mr. Jones"
        },
    },
    sunday: {
        15: { 
            subject: "biology",
            teacher: "Mr. Smith"
        },
        16: { 
            subject: "chemistry",
            teacher: "Mr. Jones"
        },
    }
}
```

As you can see, MongoDB encourages nesting of related data.

Comment: I would put the hourly records into an array, myself, like `[{time:'13:00', subject:'math', ...}]`

Comment: @Wes That brings up a great point about MongoDB - its totally flexible and there's no wrong or right way to store your data.  How you do it depends really on how you plan to use (update, query, etc) it.

Comment: +1 True enough. I would probably put the days into an array in a similar fashion, too, while I think about it. :) Makes it easier to query without being tied to a specific time or day.

Comment: Woah guys, your answers really help me, I'm going to use an array for the days. Thanks a lot. (: